# ImportError: No module named toneapp.settings - when i am running python manage.py makemigrations

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, digital-ocean

```
toneapp/
  manage.py
  toneapp/
    settings/
      __init__.py
      base_settings.py
      dev_settings.py
      production_settings.py
   urls.py
   wsgi.py

feedback/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    migrations/
       __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py

 INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'rest_framework',
  'registration',
  'adminpanel',
  'feedback',
]
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/toneapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/toneapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/toneapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/toneapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/toneapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named toneapp.settings
```

Answer (score 1):

In your hierarchy somehow you have separate `settings.py` like `base_settings.py` and `dev..` and `production...`And all are put into settings folder.

```
toneapp/
    settings/
      __init__.py
      base_settings.py
      dev_settings.py
      production_settings.py
```

Simply to say you have changed Django default hierarchy and that is the reason for error, because when Django search for `toneapp/settings`.py it cannot find it. The easiest solution is returning to default hierarchy and merging all settings in `settings.py` otherwise, you have to search and change the way Django call `settings.py` and adjust it to yours.

Comment: After all i have to make a single settings file, i was handling it with init.py file - which tells which file to import or use.
It was working very well with heroku, but was not working when i was doing this on digital ocean ubuntu machine, i wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the "os.environ.setdefault" in **manage.py** to:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'toneapp.settings.dev_settings')
```

Comment: not working like this 
gives the same error like this

ImportError: No module named toneapp.settings.production_settings

it is working with the structure i posted - on heroku
but it is not working when i am trying to make migrations on digital ocean